# After download how to open downloaded file?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

```
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
      request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.
                        DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameOfFile)
```

To open it

```
       File file = new File(Environment.
                    DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameOfFile);
            MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getName());
            String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
```

But I am getting an error message that file cannot be accessed.Check the location

Comment: Do you have the required permissions?

Comment: yes I have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/> @camelCaseCoder

Comment: Ok, is the file path correct? And are you testing this on Android 6?

Comment: No, I am testing it on KitKat path is correct I  can see the files

Comment: Did you debug and see that the file location is absolutely correct and the file is actually present?

Comment: Yes I am testing on mobile and files are saved in Downloads

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution. Note: Dont use DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME as it is deprecated in API 24. Use DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI instead.

1. Create fields downlaod manager and  a long variable to hold the download id.

   ```
   DownloadManager dm;
   long downloadId;
   String  pendingDownloadUrl = url;
   fial int storagePermissionRequestCode = 101;
   ```
2. Create download manager 
    `dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);`
3. register the broadcast receiver for download complete

   ```
    BroadcastReceiver downloadCompleteReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
           Cursor c = dm.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId));
           if (c != null) {
               c.moveToFirst();
               try {
                   String fileUri = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                   File mFile = new File(Uri.parse(fileUri).getPath());
                   String fileName = mFile.getAbsolutePath();
                   openFile(fileName);
               }catch (Exception e){
                   Log.e("error", "Could not open the downloaded file");
               }
           }
       }
   };
   ```

//register boradcast for download complete

```
registerReceiver(downloadCompleteReceiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

4. Start the download

Start the download

```
private  void onDownloadStart(String url) {
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    downloadFile(url);
} else {
    pendingDownloadUrl = url;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, storagePermissionRequestCode);
} }
```

//Download file using download manager

```
private void downlaodFile(String url){
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, null);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,filename);
    downloadId = dm.enqueue(request);//save download id for later reference }
```

//Permission status

```
@Override public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == storagePermissionRequestCode){
        boolean canDownload = true;
        for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
            if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                canDownload = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(canDownload){
            downlaodFile(pendingDownloadUrl);
        }
    }        }
```

5. Open the downloaded file

   ```
   private void openFile(String file) {
   try {
       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(file)), "application/pdf");//this is for pdf file. Use appropreate mime type
       startActivity(i);
   } catch (Exception e) {           
       Toast.makeText(this,"No pdf viewing application detected. File saved in download folder",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   }
   ```
6. Now try download your file by calling `downladFile(String url);` method

Answer (score 1):

Try using read permission:

```
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
protected void openFile(String fileName) {
    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)),
            "MIME-TYPE");
    startActivity(install);
}
```

Comment: You can also see an example here https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Internet/Download/src/com/commonsware/android/download/DownloadDemo.java

Comment: I have create a dir   final File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "Wonders"); boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdir();    how to set the path  request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, ******here****
                            , nameOfFile)@saurabh gupta